# How to make field visible only when opportunity reaches 90% probability

Tags: opportunity

I have a requirement where i have to make some field visible only when the probability reaches 90 %. Field is on opportunity

Is doing through workflow rule is the best way to do that. Or any other way through best practices.

Answer (score 14):

If your organization has Enterprise Edition of Salesforce, you can create a separate Record Type for Opportunity and a Page Layout for that Record type in which the field in question is added.

Remove the field from your default page layout then create a Workflow Rule that fires when the Stage that reflects the 90% probability is selected. Create a field update that will change the record type from your default record type to the one which displays the field.

You can create a validation rule to make sure that the record type is not selected unless probability is 90% to make sure they don't select it when creating a new Opp.

Comment: [Professional Edition](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/new-editions-2016.html) is getting record types and page layouts, too. The More You Know.

Comment: @sfdcfox True, this is a HUGE benefit to any/all on PE. Addition of Profiles is also another huge addition! Cheers.

Comment: also - vote for this Idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC -- only 66,000 vote points - perhaps it will get delivered when it reaches 100,000

Comment: If you are considering moving to lightning, the "sales path" functionality allows you to feature / highlight specific fields at specific stages.